# curb (curl for Ruby) not using cookiejar properly

Tags: ruby, cookies, curl

I'm seeing some weird behavior with curb and it's cookiejar. In irb:

```
>> require 'curl'
=> true
>> a = Curl::Easy.new
=> #<Curl::Easy>
>> a.enable_cookies = true
=> true
>> a.cookiejar = "cookies.txt"
=> "cookies.txt"
>> a.url = "http://www.amazon.com"
=> "http://www.amazon.com"
>> a.perform
=> true
```

Here I would like to have some way of retrieving the cookies amazon.com placed, but I'm unable to do so. The cookies.txt file I specified as my cookiejar does not exist and the #cookies method just returns nil. However, if I exit irb, the cookies.txt file appears with the proper cookies inside. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: After digging through the source of curb a little, I've learned that the Curl::Easy#cookiejar= method is setting the CURLOPT_COOKIJAR option mentioned [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html), and according to the documentation, the cookies are not supposed to be written to that file until 'curl_easy_cleanup(3)' is called (which must happen when you close irb, and, I've also leaned, happens when you call Curl::Easy#close). I still can't figure out how to access the cookies before closing irb/the Curl::Easy instance though....

Comment: The cookies are kept within the handle so if you do another request using the same handle the cookies will be used accordingly

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'm using curb to write some tests that require me to examine whether certain cookies were set properly. Thus, I'm interested in seeing what's in the cookie jar rather than using the cookie jar to make subsequent requests. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how the ruby binding works, but in the underlying libcurl API, the cookie jar isn't saved until the handle is "killed" with [curl_easy_cleanup](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html)(). I would presume that lots of OO-languages don't call that function on a libcurl "object" until it is killed/garbage collected somehow or if the binding provides a way to explicitly kill the libcurl object/handle.